# C++ error: Assignment of read-only member in class constructor

Tags: c++, class, oop

I am trying to assign a constant class member in my class constructor. However, I receive the following error:

> Assignment of read-only member 'ExampleClass::exampleMember'

Below is my code for the header file (ExampleClass.h)

```
class ExampleClass
{
  public:
    ExampleClass(int n);
  protected:
    const int exampleMember;
};
```

Below is my code for the implementation file (ExampleClass.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ExampleClass.h"
using namespace std;
ExampleClass::ExampleClass(int n)
{
    this->exampleMember = n;
}
```

Comment: `ExampleClass::ExampleClass(int n) : exampleMember (n) {}`?

Comment: Impossible to get this error with code shown. As shown [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NBCDkTl3TGOGUpUx). Even if you want to ask about different error, not shown in initial question - that is a different question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor can intialize `exampleMember` using an initializer list:

```
ExampleClass::ExampleClass(int n) : exampleMember(n)
{
}
```

a special syntax placed outside the body of the constructor.